# How to sort json to text?

Tags: c#, json.net

How can i sort a string from JsonText string to Sorted strings?

From

```
{
"A": "Command",
"B": [],
"C": "leaderboard.leaderboard",
"D": 3,
"E": "get_leaderboard_infos"
}
```

to

```
A : Command
D : 3
E : get_leaderboard_infos
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Why `C : leaderboard.leaderboard` doesn't apperat in the output?

Comment: i want to remove unwanted result like C:

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First use [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx) to parse the JSON text into objects.  Once they are objects, you can sort or filter the objects in a list based on their values.

In order to "prune" the objects, meaning get rid of unwanted properties and values, simply create a different object that only has the properties you like, and copy the values from the JSON.Net output to your new objects, and then serialize your new objects into a new JSON string.